# Include A Bundle Package Dependency In JAR Form

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, manifest

I am admittedly novice to Java and Eclipse so if I say something unclear please correct me as I want to learn. I am doing some development for someone who is using the Knime framework and has dependencies on a few different packages. I was able to pull down all packages but one. The one I was unable to pull down contains some confidential information so it is not on the shared repo. It was emailed to me as a JAR file and I need this JAR to be recognized as the missing package in the dependencies.

Here is what I currently have:

**Manfest**

`Require-Bundle: 
    org.eclipse.core.runtime,
    org.knime.workbench.core,
    org.knime.workbench.repository,
    org.knime.base,
    org.apache.commons.lang;bundle-version="2.6.0",
    com.example.included.and.working;bundle-version="1.0.0",
    com.example.need.this.jar;bundle-version="1.0.0"` <--- This line is can not find bundle

I have tried adding selecting the project, moving to the build tab, and adding the JAR as a library.

I have also put the JAR in the Lib folder and tried something like this,

```
Bundle-ClassPath: 
   googleapiconnector.jar, // Included jar for project
   lib/com.example.need.this.jar
```

But I had no luck with this either.

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What is this jar? If it is an Eclipse plugin it needs to be in the Require-Bundle and you probably need to add it to your target platform.

Comment: It is not an Eclipse plugin, its just a compiled package that contains a class with Authorization credentials. Rather then sending me over the raw JAVA with the credentials in he sent me the compiled version as a JAR. Obviously if I pull the other packages into Eclipse then Eclipse detects those packages. So given someone takes that raw package that is just Java classes and puts it into a JAR, how would I replicate the traditional adding of a package?

Answer (score 0):

The jar should be in the Bundle-Classpath and the project classpath.

Use the MANIFEST.MF editor, on the Runtime tab add the jar to the Classpath section. This should update both locations.